# building Python py2app issue on Mac

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying to build an MacOS app using Python and py2app. The build error I get is

> No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/py2app-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/py2app/bundletemplate/prebuilt/main-i386'

I searched in multiple directories and files but I am unable to determine where Python or py2app is getting the path from. The prebuilt that it needs to use is called: `main-intel`.

Where is it pulling main-i386 from? Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use to version 0.5.3.

```
svn co http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk py2app
cd py2app
sudo /usr/bin/python setup.py install
ls /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/py2app-0.5.3-py2.6.egg/py2app/bundletemplate/prebuilt/
main-fat       main-fat3      main-i386      main-intel     main-ppc       main-ppc64     main-universal main-x86_64
```

[py2app - Create standalone Mac OS X applications with Python](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)